# how to run run LMbench on mac

Tags: macos, gcc

I followed [these instructions](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/run_lmbench.html). Download lmbench3.tar.gz from [lmbench3](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lmbench3.tar.gz)
and Unpack LMbench to create a tree like so:

```
lmbench/
    Results/
    doc/
    scripts/
    src/
```

And Go to the `lmbench` directory, and type `make results see`

But the result is wrong:

```
 7 warnings generated.
    gcc -O -DRUSAGE -DHAVE_uint=1 -DHAVE_uint64_t=1 -DHAVE_int64_t=1 -DHAVE_DRAND48   -c getopt.c -o ../bin/i686-apple-darwin15.6.0/getopt.o
    gcc -O -DRUSAGE -DHAVE_uint=1 -DHAVE_uint64_t=1 -DHAVE_int64_t=1 -DHAVE_DRAND48   -c lib_sched.c -o ../bin/i686-apple-darwin15.6.0/lib_sched.o
    lib_sched.c:94:3: error: non-void function 'handle_scheduler' should return a
          value [-Wreturn-type]
                    return;
                    ^
    1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [../bin/i686-apple-darwin15.6.0/lib_sched.o] Error 1 
    make[1]: *** [lmbench] Error 2
    make: *** [build] Error 2
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Instead of posting a link, include necessary code directly in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the statement

```
return;
```

into

```
return 0;
```

at line 94 of lib_sched.c

Then this file should compile without this error.

Comment: I also had to correct for error that said `No rule to make target '../SCCS/s.ChangeSet', needed by 'bk.ver'. Stop.` by invoking `mkdir ./SCCS` and `touch ./SCCS/s.ChangeSet` as described [here](https://github.com/zhanglongqi/linux-tips/blob/master/tools/benchmark.md) or [here](http://kongll.github.io/2015/04/24/LMbench/).